# How to perform simple arithmetic operations on columns of 2D arrays in Eigen

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, eigen, eigen3

I am very new to Eigen, and have the following minimal example of my issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <typename T>
struct arr_holder
{
  explicit arr_holder(Eigen::ArrayBase<T> const &loc)
      : local_arr {decltype(local_arr)::Zero(loc.rows(), loc.cols())}
  { 
      do_calc(loc);
  }

  auto do_calc(Eigen::ArrayBase<T> const &data) -> void
  {
    auto &&data_col  = data.col(0);
    auto &&local_col = local_arr.col(0);

    std::cout << data_col - local_col << '\n';
  }

 private:
  Eigen::Array<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> local_arr;
};

int main() {
  Eigen::Array<double, 3, 3> data;
  data << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0;

  auto arr = arr_holder(data);
}
```

This code fails to compile with Eigen 3.3.4 and Clang 5.0.1, with the error

> ```
> eigen/Eigen/src/Core/AssignEvaluator.h:833:3: error: static_assert failed "YOU_MIXED_MATRICES_OF_DIFFERENT_SIZES"
>   EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_SAME_MATRIX_SIZE(ActualDstTypeCleaned,Src)
> ```

stemming from the line in `do_calc` where I am attempting to subtract the columns.

My question is, why doesn't this work? My (naive) understanding would lead me to believe that I can perform an element-wise subtraction of columns between the locally zeroed 2D-array and the `data` array, since the columns appear to have the same shape (checked by printing out the number of rows and columns of `data_col` and `local_col`), and the type is the same.

What am I misunderstanding here, and what is the correct way to perform such column-wise operations between a class-owned 2D array and a 2D array passed as an argument? My suspicion is that I am misusing `Dynamic` arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subtracting an array of double and a array of 3x3 arrays, which is not allowed. Perhaps you meant to write:

```
Eigen::Array<typename T::Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> local_arr;
```

Comment: Oh dear -_- I see what I was doing now, I neglected to realize that the data type I was passing was actually an array. Thank you!